# Add thousands comma separator to Relplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, seaborn

How can I add a thousands comma separator to a Seaborn Relplot in Python?

My code is below:

```
g = sns.relplot(
    x='date',
    y='count',
    kind='line',
    data=df
)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr

for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(
        tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: format(int(y), ',')))
```